# disable the "enter" key in a form if the field is not valid

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, key

how to disable the "enter" key who give us the possibility to valid and send the form if the field is not valid ?

I only did the first part, which indicates that the field is not valid, but the "enter" key is always active . So my question is simple, how to disable the "enter" key button from the moment we see the "error-message" under the field

here is my test page ->

```
http://500milligrammes.com/facticemagazine/final/unsubscribe/
```

Comment: This is a terrible idea to rely only on the enter key. All keyboards don't have an enter key, like on certain mobiles. You should at least add a validation button. Plus you can use the change js event to check if the mail is valid with a Regex, and activate the submission button if it is all right

Comment: Hummmm okey @Dean i think you're right. Have you an exemple or a tuto who explain how to show the submit button is the field is valid ?

Comment: if you set `type="email"` in your input it will require the user to insert a mail address. This way however only means than there should be an _@_. If you want something better you'll have to add `pattern = "sth"` and create (or find) a regexp for e-mails. Also you should add the code `required=true`

Comment: you're right @HéctorE, i ever did that, that's why you have a red error message if we don't write an email valid, but now i want to disable the enter key if this field is invalid ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked your website, to achieve what you asked for:

```
$("#name").on("keydown", function(e) {
    if(e.which === 13 && $("#name").next(".error-message").is(":visible")) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

The submit is always send on `keydown`, so we need to add a `keydown` event handler.
Next is to check if the key was the enter key `e.which === 13` and after that we just need to check if the error message is shown or not `$("#name").next(".error-message").is(":visible")`.

If both conditions are true then just prevent the default action (submit) by calling `e.preventDefault();`

You can further improve this by also checking if the input is empty or not before accepting the enter key. The first keydown might be the enter key.

```
$("#name").on("keydown", function(e) {
    if(e.which === 13) {
        if($("#name").next(".error-message").is(":visible") || !$("#name").val()) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check it using the `keycode value (13)` of `enter` key.

Something like the following should do:

```
$('form').on('keyup keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        if (!isValid()) { // your validation function
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        } else {
            $(this).submit();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Try adding this when you show the error:

$(document).on('keyup keypress', 'form input[type="text"]', function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;`enter code here`
  }
});
```

Comment: That won't do what you think it does. The submit is not fired upon those events.

Comment: my goal is to disable the enter key button if the field is invalid and the red error message is visible  ;)

Comment: if (!$("#name").val().match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*\@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/i)) {
$("#name").next(".error-message").show().text("enter a valid email before to press enter");
}